# How to distinguish swelling resulting from a tendinopathy affecting an epicondyle from the normal shape of the arm?

Tags: tendinopathy, epicondylitis, swelling

http://www.niams.nih.gov/Health_Info/Bursitis/bursitis_ff.asp says:

> Bursitis and tendinitis are both common conditions that cause swelling around muscles and bones.

How to distinguish swelling resulting from a tendinopathy affecting an epicondyle from the normal shape of the arm?

Comment: I haven't found any answer so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.